# How to set attachment size limit for an individual database

Tags: couchdb, cloudant

Is there a way for restricting attachment size limits on an individual database in CouchDB?
I have a database videosdb, in my social networking site and I want to restrict attachment size on it. So that user can't upload video greater than a fixed limit.

Moreover if there is such functionality, than do it work in multipart request say during [replication](https://docs.couchdb.org/en/stable/replication/protocol.html#upload-document-with-attachments) like this.

```
PUT /target/SpaghettiWithMeatballs?new_edits=false HTTP/1.1
Accept: application/json
Content-Length: 1030
Content-Type: multipart/related; boundary="864d690aeb91f25d469dec6851fb57f2"
Host: localhost:5984
User-Agent: CouchDB
```

Answer (score 2):

There is no out-of-the-box way to do this on a per-database level. However, you can likely accomplish your goal by writing an [update function](https://docs.couchdb.org/en/stable/ddocs/ddocs.html#update-functions) for that database, which rejects documents that contain attachments that are too large.

But note that it is not advisable to use CouchDB to store large attachments anyway, as CouchDB was not designed for this use case, and is not particularly efficient for that type of load. It is generally considered best practice to store large attachments externally such as in an S3 bucket or similar, and have your CouchDB documents reference them by ID or URL.

Answer (score 2):

As for replication, you can write validate_doc_update function, which will sum all `.length` props of each attachment, and reject a doc if the limit was reached. Replicated docs always have that prop for each attachment.

This however generally doesn’t hold for saving docs, since json being saved may not have `.length` props for new attachments.